# what is different between return View::make() and return Response::view()?

Tags: php, laravel-4

when we want to return the "welcome" view, is there any different between return View::make("welcome") and return Response::view("welcome")?

if there is different, what is it? when we should use Response::view(), when we should use View::make()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each response contains a view. 
In your example, there is no difference.
But using Response::view() you can also set response headers.

```
Response::view('hello')->header('Content-Type', $type);
```

View::make is always HTML, Response can be XML, JSON..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Laravel programmer, but in most of the frameworks I've used, you usually have two options for views: 1) return the view as a string or 2) output the view directly to the response stream. It sounds to me like `View::make()` might be the former and `Response::view()` the latter. You can test this by trying to set the value of `Response::view()` to a variable, and then see if you can output that variable later in execution. If it does indeed render the response directly to output I believe you will get a "headers already sent" error when you try to output after the `Response::view()` call.